# How to make something like router-outlet of angular in Reactjs?

Tags: angular, reactjs

I have **sideBarMenuComponent** which contains the following code in render()

```
     <ul>
        <li><Link to='/home'>Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/settings'>Settings</Link></li>
      </ul>
```

and another  **MasterLayoutComponent** which render HomeComponent and
SettingsComponent in the main-content in render()

```
       <div className="MasterLayoutComponent">
          <Header />
            <div className="main-content">
               <Route exact path='/home' component={HomeComponent} />
               <Route exact path='/settings' component={SettingsComponet} />
            </div>
          <Footer />
        </div>
```

But when I click on the Links of sideBarMenuComponent the HomeComponent and the SettingsComponet aren't rendered, What is the wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Router Outlet is a good features in Angular and I tried to research it for React. Hope that I can help you. ^^
I got my answer in these links: 
1) https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-outlet
2) https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-outlet

Comment: Welcome to SO, Can you explain a little bit more the concepts from the links here.

Answer (score 0):

Two points are missing in your code.

- You didn't import your sidebar component in parent component.
- You didn't wrap your overall container inside 'Router'.

After adding these steps your code will look like,

```
<div className="MasterLayoutComponent">
<Router>
          <Header />
          <Sidebar />
            <div className="main-content">
               <Route exact path='/home' component={HomeComponent} />
               <Route exact path='/settings' component={SettingsComponet} />
            </div>
          <Footer />
</Router>
        </div>
```

Make sure to import BrowserRouter as Router and Sidebar components.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late on this but there is actually `<Outlet />` available in React Router.

You can find the more information [here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet).

Example :

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
// Other imports

function Dashboard() {
    return (
    <div>
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>

        {/* This element will render either <DashboardMessages> when the URL is
            "/messages", <DashboardTasks> at "/tasks", or null if it is "/"
        */}
        <Outlet />
    </div>
    );
}

function App() {
    return (
        <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />}>
            <Route
            path="messages"
            element={<DashboardMessages />}
            />
            <Route path="tasks" element={<DashboardTasks />} />
        </Route>
        </Routes>
    );
}
```